# Auto increment is not working in SQLite database

Tags: android, sqlite, android-sqlite, sqliteopenhelper

I am working in sqlite database. I have a product table which has a product id, name, price, and a company id I made to be the primary key and autoincrement when I add products to the database, but productid seems to be empty

**Here's a screenshot of my database**
[image]

**Here's my database class**

```html
package com.example.abdelmagied.myapplication;

import android.content.Context;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;

/**
 * Created by AbdELMagied on 7/24/2017.
 */

public class database extends SQLiteOpenHelper {


    private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "product.db";
    private static final String TABLE_NAME    = "myproduct";

  /// columns in the database
    private static final String COL1_NAME     = "productId";
    private static final String COL2_NAME     = "productSalary";
    private static final String COL3_NAME     = "companyname";
    private static final String COL4_NAME     = "productName";


    // constructor
    public database(Context context) {

        super(context, DATABASE_NAME  , null , 1);
    }


    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase) {
        sqLiteDatabase.execSQL("create table myproduct ("+COL1_NAME+" integer primary key  autoincrement, "+COL2_NAME+" text , "+COL3_NAME+" text , "+COL4_NAME+" text)");
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase, int i, int i1) {
           sqLiteDatabase.execSQL("drop database " + DATABASE_NAME );
           onCreate(sqLiteDatabase);
    }
}
```

**This is the activity at which I insert in database**

```html
package com.example.abdelmagied.myapplication;

import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;

public class addproduct extends AppCompatActivity {
    public Button AddToDatabase;
    public EditText productName , productSalary , companyMade;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_addproduct);

        // get the button id
         AddToDatabase = (Button) findViewById(R.id.AddDatabase);

        // handle the action of the click
        AddToDatabase.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                // get the entered info from the edittexts
                productName   = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.PNameId);
                productSalary =(EditText) findViewById(R.id.PSalaryId);
                companyMade   = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.PSalaryId);

                //add to database productName , productSalary , companyMade...
                  database mydata = new database(getApplicationContext());
                  SQLiteDatabase db = mydata.getWritableDatabase();
                  ContentValues content = new ContentValues();
                  content.put("productSalary"  , productSalary.getText().toString());
                  content.put("companyname" , companyMade.getText().toString());
                  content.put("productName" , productName.getText().toString());
                  db.insert("myproduct" , null , content);

            }
        });

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using your SQL for the table creation i.e.

```
`sqLiteDatabase.execSQL("create table myproduct ("+COL1_NAME+" integer primary key  autoincrement, "+COL2_NAME+" text , "+COL3_NAME+" text , "+COL4_NAME+" text)");`
```

And then using the following to test :-

```
            dbhlp = new SO45290855(this);

            SQLiteDatabase dbx = dbhlp.getWritableDatabase();
            ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
            cv.put(SO45290855.COL2_NAME,"xxxx");
            cv.put(SO45290855.COL3_NAME,"yyyy");
            cv.put(SO45290855.COL4_NAME,"zzzz");
            dbx.insert(SO45290855.TABLE_NAME,null,cv);
            ContentValues cv2 = new ContentValues();
            cv2.put(SO45290855.COL2_NAME,"xxxx");
            cv2.put(SO45290855.COL3_NAME,"yyyy");
            cv2.put(SO45290855.COL4_NAME,"zzzz");
            dbx.insert(SO45290855.TABLE_NAME,null,cv);


            Cursor csr = dbx.query(SO45290855.TABLE_NAME,null,null,null,null,null,null);

            while (csr.moveToNext()) {
                for (int i=0; i < csr.getColumnCount();i++) {
                    Log.d("CsrPos_" + Integer.toString(csr.getPosition()),
                            "Column=" + csr.getColumnName(i) +
                                    " Data=" + csr.getString(i)
                    );
                }
            }
```

the output given is :-

```
07-25 09:30:41.721 2965-2965/? D/CsrPos_0: Column=productId Data=1
07-25 09:30:41.721 2965-2965/? D/CsrPos_0: Column=productSalary Data=xxxx
07-25 09:30:41.721 2965-2965/? D/CsrPos_0: Column=companyname Data=yyyy
07-25 09:30:41.721 2965-2965/? D/CsrPos_0: Column=productName Data=zzzz
07-25 09:30:41.721 2965-2965/? D/CsrPos_1: Column=productId Data=2
07-25 09:30:41.721 2965-2965/? D/CsrPos_1: Column=productSalary Data=xxxx
07-25 09:30:41.721 2965-2965/? D/CsrPos_1: Column=companyname Data=yyyy
07-25 09:30:41.721 2965-2965/? D/CsrPos_1: Column=productName Data=zzzz
```

***SO45290855*** being a copy of your database class

As such, due to the first line showing **productId** has a value of **1** and also that the 5th line shows the **porductId**, in the 2nd row, has a value of **2**, in principle the code you have should create the same.

Therefore it is very likely that you have amended the code to change the structure but have not realised that `onCreate` basically runs once for the lifetime of the database file and thus unless you have deleted the database file, changes to the structure will not be applied.

**The likely solution is to clear the App's data or to uninstall the App and rerun.**

Further to this you very likely do not need to code AUTOINCREMENT using `column_name INTEGER PRIMARY KEY` will result in an incrementing column.

I'd suggest reading [SQLite Autoincrement](https://sqlite.org/autoinc.html)  which includes

> The AUTOINCREMENT keyword imposes extra CPU, memory, disk space, and
>   disk I/O overhead and should be avoided if not strictly needed. It is
>   usually not needed.